# Track a (once been deleted) file

Tags: git, version-control, tig

Here's my case:
A file been added, removed and added again (same name).

How do I track time stamp prior to it's most recently adding?

```
file:       file.c ---> null ---> file.c
status:     added     removed     added
traceable:    ?          ?          ✓
```

I use `tig` but open to any `git` interface.

Comment: What do you mean by *track time stamp*? In Git, files do not have time stamps. *Commits* have time stamps (two each), but files don't.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to track the commit time stamp, you can use any of the commands below in bash:

```
git whatchanged file.c
git show file.c
git log file.c
git log -p file.c
```